# Django Admin Adding data

Tags: python, django, admin

I am trying to learn Django through Coding for Entrepreneur. The problem is in the tutorial, when the tutor adds the models in the admin.py, the values of the fields are shown. While I do it, it shows "something object" only.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Join(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField() 
    ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='ABC', unique=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='ABC')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.email)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("email", "ref_id",)


class JoinFriends(models.Model):
    email = models.OneToOneField(Join, related_name="Sharer")
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(Join, related_name="Friend", null=True, blank=True)
    emailall = models.ForeignKey(Join, related_name="emailall")

    def __unicode__(self):
        print(self.friends.all())
        print(self.emailall)
        print(self.email)
        return (self.friends.all()[0].email)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Join, JoinFriends 

class JoinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__unicode__', 'timestamp', 'updated']

    class Meta:
        model = Join

admin.site.register(Join, JoinAdmin)
admin.site.register(JoinFriends)
```

**How it should be**
[image]
**How it is happening when I am doing it**
[image]
How can I solve this problem.

Thank you for the help

The above shown page should come when clicked on Add join friends. It is shown perfectly in the following page when I add the following code as well in admin.py

```
class FriendAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__unicode__']


admin.site.register(JoinFriends, FriendAdmin)
```

[image]
However, when I click on Add join friends, the page is as shown above in figure1.

[image]

**When using def __str___(self) function:**

Comment: hello, as you can see. the main page is working. but the page when i click on add is not showing exact values. instead it is showing Join object

Comment: Is the unclosed double quotes in the unicode function a typo?

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: if using python 3, you need to define `def __str__(self):` instead of `__unicode__`

Comment: it is returning a string. even when i edit the models.py and remove JoinFriends class and just add

friend = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name="referral", null=True, blank=True)

Comment: it is showing Friend and dropdown and join object in the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using python 3. In python 3, `__str__` is used instead of `__unicode__`.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods for more information.

Comment: when i use __str__, it shows above when i runserver

Comment: Remove `__unicode__` from your `list_display` in `FriendAdmin` class.

Comment: whats the equivalent of list_display with __str__?

Comment: Remove `list_display` entirely, and it will default to use `__str__`. `list_display` are better used when you want to display individual fields divided into columns. It's supposed to contain field names, such as `list_display = ("email", "name")`. Also, please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works. When using Python 3, add

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db import models
@python_2_unicode_compatible
```

and remove list_display from admin.py's class

Appreciated the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Python 3 expects `__str__` whereas Python 2 expects `__unicode__`.

Calling the object in Admin without a `__str__` method results in the generic `Join object` being displayed in admin. Anything you define in the `__str__` method will be displayed, instead.

Further, when in Py3, you should not use a call to `__unicode__` in your `list_display`, since it won't know what you're talking about. I'm guessing using the imports you supplied in your own answer allows this to function properly, but moving forward, you should simply use `__str__` where you would otherwise use `__unicode__`.

Comment: in the main page, now only one field is shown. how to show necessary fields in python 3 as done with list_object in python 3?

Comment: Simply add each field to `list_display`. This is a list of which fields or methods from your model to display in the changelist. You cannot display a many-to-many field directly, but the rest can. For instance, you might try `list_display = ['__str__', 'email', 'emailall']`.